# Incorporating a preexisting database into a new django project

Tags: django

I've been working on a website using PHP with MySQL. I've decided that learning Django will speed things up by leveraging my experience with Python. So, the task is to redevelop the site using Django.

My question is the following:

> Is it more sensible to plug the existing database into Django as is, or is it more sensible to set up a database with Django and then transfer the old database's tables in, somehow?

I have no idea which of these options is possible, feasible or relatively problematic.

Comment: you can use the existing database, "python manage.py inspectdb > db_models.py" will create the models automatically for you.

Comment: @erdimeola Great, thank you for the pointers. I'll be sure to follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While django is more suitable to work with new databases, you can definitely hook it up to an existing one. You'll have to work a bit to do it, and create your models to fit your tables, but it's not very complicated. You even have an easy method to auto-create the models for you, [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/):

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

The result usually needs some cleaning, but it does most of the work. Then all you have to do is use `syncdb` (or `migrate` if using south) to add additional tables required by django.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and the advice! I have some reading to do, and then I'll be sure to follow up here!